# How can I select a grouped row where it only contains null values in another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, sql-null

It's a bit confusing, so I'll try to exemplify in the table below:

***example-table***

| id | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 1 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

So, grouping by the same ID, I only want to display those IDs that all their data, from all columns, are null. In the table example above, only IDs 1 and 4.

The code I'm trying to use - just for reference:

```
select id
from example-table
group by id, data1, data2, data3
having data1 is null and data2 is null and data3 is null;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Answer (score 4):

You can group by id only and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
HAVING COALESCE(MAX(data1), MAX(data2), MAX(data3)) IS NULL;
```